# Azure Functions to de-duplicate ingestion data

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I am polling a 3rd-party API with an Azure Functions every 5 seconds. The API always returns a JSON message even if the response has not changed since the last time I read it.

Currently I am writing the json response to the data lake and handling deduping with a batch process. I now want to move the deduping logic into the function so that I record the last successful write to the data lake and only write the response again if it has changed.

My thoughts are that serverless functions should be stateless, so I would have to record the ID of the last successful record (or maybe the hash of the whole response) to a Name/Value pair in Table Storage. Then on the next execute I check if it has changed and proceed or not.

Another option might be durable functions - there seems to be a way of writing state with IDurableEntityContext ctx:

```
[FunctionName("Counter")]
public static void Counter([EntityTrigger] IDurableEntityContext ctx)
{
    switch (ctx.OperationName.ToLowerInvariant())
    {
        case "add":
            ctx.SetState(ctx.GetState<int>() + ctx.GetInput<int>());
            break;
        case "reset":
            ctx.SetState(0);
            break;
        case "get":
            ctx.Return(ctx.GetState<int>());
            break;
    }
}
```

I am concerned that neither solution would handle the frequency of a read/write every 5 seconds reliably.
Can someone confirm if either of these are a good solution and reliable for the use case? (or perhaps some other solution all together for pulling data from an API and only proceeding if it has changed since last read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have to create a hash of the resource. In fact, if 3rd Party API was implemented correctly, it should have returned an ETag in the response payload of your first GET on the resource. You may then persist the `resoureId:eTag` mapping in Table storage. The next time you poll the API for the same resource, include the `eTag` as part of the request payload. The 3rd Party API should return a 304 response code if the entity has not changed.

Assuming that ETag checks are supported by the 3rd Party API, you should be able to either create a Timer-based function to poll the API or orchestrate your workflow using the [Monitor Pattern in Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-monitor?tabs=csharp).

Comment: Thanks Ling, I will look into the ETag on the API. What is your opinion of using Durable Entities for the state instead of doing it manually to table storage?

Comment: Yes, Durable Entities should work if you don’t want to rely on Table storage although I have not tried Durable Entities myself. Hope it works for you!